# the meaning of 'fin' here

Tags: word-meaning, slang

> 1)I mean his phone bill alone last year must have come to twenty G's
>   (he's got lines open to all the tracks and ballparks all day long,
>   you know), but only ten years ago he would have had to sweat blood
>   before he coulda raised a lousy ***fin***.
>
> 2)But they were extremely fond of Max, anyway. He didn't push, he was
>   always good for a ***fin***, and though he never complained, it had been
>   hard for him since his wife died.
>
> -The Apprenticeship of Duddy Kravitz by Mordecai Richler -

I looked '***fin***' up in the dictionary. It means a five dollar bill in slang, but it doesn't make sense here. What is the meaning of '***fin***' here?

Answer (score 2):

As Teacher KSHuang noted in the comments:

Why doesn't a five-dollar bill make sense here? It makes sense to me. 1) Before, he used to have trouble scrounging up even five dollars. 2) He was always generous with lending (some) money to friends.

Comment: Perhaps the OP is unclear on "raise" and or "good for" in this context?